# How to make where query in HttpGet request in .net core web api

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to make a `HttpGet` request in my ASP.NET Core Web API.

The problem is that I don't know how to make get request with query.

This is my model:

```
public class Predoslepozicie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int idZamestnanca { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Pozicia { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DatumUkoncenia { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DatumNastupu { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
// GET: api/Predoslepozicie/5
[HttpGet("{idZamestnanca}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Predoslepozicie>> GetPredoslepozicie(int idZamestnanca)
{
    var Predoslepozicie = await _context.Predoslepozicie.FindAsync(idZamestnanca);

    if (Predoslepozicie == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Predoslepozicie;
}
```

`idZamestnanca` is an id from another table in the SQL database, and I need to select all rows `where id = x`.

For example `idZamestnanca = 9` appears in the table 10 times and I need the query to return just these 10 rows.

When I try to make request with `idZamestnanca`, I get a status 404.

Comment: How are you sending the request? Could you please share your full controller class? Not sure how did you set that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to make request with idZamestnanca, I get a status 404.

There may two major reasons for your 404 you are getting now.

When controller hits but returns with 404:

[image]

Let's imagine this is your table. You would like to search by `idZamestnanca` from this table. Here `PrimaryKey` is `Id`. But you would like to search by `idZamestnanca` in that case `FindAsync(idZamestnanca)` will not work. Because [`FindAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.findasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) finds an entity with the given primary key values so `FindAsync` will always return 404.on

Solution for your scenario:

Instead of that you should use below code to execute your query:

```cs
 var Predoslepozicie =  _context.Predoslepozicies.Where(id=>id.idZamestnanca == idZamestnanca).ToList();
```

**Note:** When you would replace above query then it would yell at you.

[image]

Because this a `List` But you have defined a single object `Task<ActionResult<Predoslepozicie>>` here.

**Final fixing:**

Replace either `Task<ActionResult<List<Predoslepozicie>>>` this so your controller action should be look like below:

```cs
        [HttpGet("{idZamestnanca}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<List<Predoslepozicie>>> GetPredoslepozicie(int idZamestnanca)
        {
            var Predoslepozicie = _context.Predoslepozicies.Where(id => id.idZamestnanca == idZamestnanca).ToList();

            if (Predoslepozicie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Predoslepozicie;
        }
```

Or you can simply do like below:

**Good Practice:**

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FrodoNicitelController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public FrodoNicitelController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        [HttpGet("{idZamestnanca}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetPredoslepozicie(int idZamestnanca)
        {
            var Predoslepozicie = _context.Predoslepozicies.Where(id => id.idZamestnanca == idZamestnanca).ToList();

            if (Predoslepozicie == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(Predoslepozicie);
        }
        
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**When controller doesn't hit and returns with 404:**

In this case you are not sending your [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-with-http-verb-attributes) correctly. When you set your route attribute as like `[HttpGet("{idZamestnanca}")]`, in that scenario you have to call your API URL like below:

```
https://localhost:7132/api/YourControllerName/101 // Need to call like this
```

**Note:** Remember that, here you have to pass your parameter directly after `controller` followed by `/` (backslash) not by `?` or like below:

```
 https://localhost:7132/api/YourControllerName?idZamestnanca=1 // Not like this
```